# Iterate over a dataframe after set index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a want to make his index start from 1 instead of 0. I can do it with no problems like the example below

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.index += 1
```

but, when I try to iterate over the rows it raises the error `"single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"` when the last index is reached, see:

```
for index, line in df.iterrows():
  print(df.loc[index])
```

How can I iterate over the dataframe even when I reindex him?

Comment: you should change print(df.loc[i]) to print(df.loc[index])

Comment: `i` is not `index` (and vise-versa)

Comment: now it raises another error: "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" Should I update the question?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, index=range(1, len(data) + 1))

df.index += 1

or

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

DataFrame
df.index = range(1, len(df) + 1)

df.index += 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.loc[index]` instead `df.iloc[index]` solved the problem. Seems that `iloc[]` keeps indexing from zero, independently of the dataframe index.